# Query Nested Object and Get the Desired Key in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have this document with this structure

```json
{
    "itemA": {
        "subItemA": {
            "20200104": [
                {
                    "item": 1,
                    "item2": 2,
                    "item3": 3
                },
                {
                    "item": 4,
                    "item2": 5,
                    "item3": 6
                },
                {
                    "item": 7,
                    "item2": 8,
                    "item3": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I know the key of `itemA`, `subItemA`, and `20200104` and i want to retrieve the data so it will look like this:

```json
[
    {
        "item": 1,
        "item2": 2,
        "item3": 3
    },
    {
        "item": 4,
        "item2": 5,
        "item3": 6
    },
    {
        "item": 7,
        "item2": 8,
        "item3": 9
    }
]
```

This may be possible if I use JavaScript function (like `db.data.find().forEach(function () ....`) but is it possible to only use the "native query"?

Comment: Keys(subItemA, 20200104) are know or unknown?

Comment: @Ashh itemA, subItemA, and 20200104 are known. Thanks for the correction I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `$unwind` the array then use `$replaceRoot`

```
   db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: "$itemA.subItemA.20200104"
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: "$itemA.subItemA.20200104"
        }
      }
    ])
```